# Universal Windows App application start page can not be determined

Tags: visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app

When debugging a HTML/JS Universal Windows app in VS 2015, there's the typical "Break", "Stop debugging", "Restart" buttons. Next to that is a "Refresh Windows App" button which is supposed to update the UI with any changes you made to the code without restarting the entire app. For some reason, whenever I click that nothing happens and the button just ends up being greyed out. In the Output console, the error message that appears is this:

`Cannot refresh project <project> because an application start page could not be determined.`

Any idea what I'm missing to cause that error?